# How to correctly compose a query with r2dbc @Query for three value options: true, false, null ? (postgresql)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, r2dbc, nativequery

I'm trying to make a request to get data from the database

The boolean value of three options comes into the parameters:

1. false - show entities with false
2. true - show entity with true
3. null - any option corresponding to user_id

But I can't figure out what to do with null

```
@Repository
public interface Repo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Device,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM device where user_id = $1 and show = $2")
    Flux<Device> findByUserIdAndShow(String userId, Boolean show);

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to change the title to "How to handle native queries with R2DBC when a parameter can be null but its place in SQL doesn't allow null" or similar :) And I slightly changed your tags - if you disagree feel free to change them back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM device where user_id = $1 and ($2 is null or show = $2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create simple unconditional native queries and put the business logic into a default method, which serves as a central "switch".

```java
public interface Repo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Device,Long> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM device WHERE user_id = :userId AND show = :show")
    Flux<Device> doFindByUserIdAndShow(@NonNull String userId, boolean show);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM device WHERE user_id = :userId")
    Flux<Device> findByUserId(@NonNull String userId);

    default Flux<Device> findByUserIdAndShow(@NonNull String userId, @Nullable Boolean show) {
        if (show == null) {
            return findByUserId(String userId);
        }
        return findByUserIdAndShow(userId, show);
    }
}
```

In your particular case it doesn't make a big difference, but it usually produces more readable SQL and gives you better flexibility.

Imagine a situation when you have a table with an ID by default generated by the database, but sometimes you need to generate the ID by your Java code, such as

```sql
CREATE TABLE mail
(
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    received timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    sender text NOT NULL,
    subject text NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

Then you have the entity defined as

```java
@Data
@Builder
@Table("mail")
public class MailEntity {
    UUID id;
    Instant received;
    String sender;
    String subject;
    ...
}
```

And you want to implement an `insertMail()` which correctly handles entities with and without `id`. And yes, we have a use case for it, because sometimes the emails are created inside our microservice and sometimes outside, and thanks to UUID is a primary key we can afford storing them in a single table.

So the repository then looks like

```java
// Postgres SQL dialect
public interface MailRepository extends R2dbcRepository<MailEntity, UUID> {
    @Query("""
            INSERT INTO mail(id, received, sender, subject, ...)
                VALUES (
                    :#{#mail.id},
                    :#{#mail.received},
                    :#{#mail.sender},
                    :#{#mail.subject},
                    ...
                RETURNING *
            """)
    Mono<MailEntity> insertMailWithId(MailEntity mail);

    @Query("""
            INSERT INTO mail(received, sender, subject, ...)
                VALUES (
                    :#{#mail.received},
                    :#{#mail.sender},
                    :#{#mail.subject},
                    ...
                RETURNING *
            """)
    Mono<MailEntity> insertMailWithoutId(MailEntity mail);

    default Mono<MailEntity> insertMail(MailEntity mail) {
        if (mail.getId() == null) {
            return insertMailWithoutId(mail);
        }
        return insertMailWithId(mail);
    }
}
```